# Why are there two thin vertical lines through all of my photos?

Tags: troubleshooting, artifacts

[image][image: y]I have a recently purchased Nikon 5100. Since purchase there is a series of two lines (in the same place) in the frame that show up on the pictures. Any guesses as to what they are and how I can get rid of them?  The lines go the length o the picture -top to bottom and anything in that section of the frame will have the two lines. It happens with and without flash.

You can see in photo below on right hand side next to the two girls on right the 2 lines clearly.

Comment: Interesting how it looks exactly like what happened when you got grit in the film transport mechanism...back in the film days. Grit would rub along the film emulsion, creating scratches exactly like this.

Comment: Is one of these images cropped? The lines are not in the same place on both of them.

Comment: He's, the image with the girls is cropped. When I took a series of pictures of the girls in a group the lines were down the same person each time so it appears they are in the same spot on the camera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A NEF file would be good to see before anything, but most probably you need to send the camera for servicing. If in USA, you can try https://repair.nikonusa.com/ProductEntry

Answer (score 1):

If they are showing up at the same place on every image, then this is most likely a failure of either the sensor or the electronics that pull the data off of the sensor. Either way, that's something that needs to be evaluated and repaired by Nikon.